# C# generic serialization utility class

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization, constraints

I have an existing class for serializing and deserializing objects to/from XML.  It's a generic class with a single type parameter `T` whose only constraint is `where T : IXmlSerializable`.  However, I want to still be able to use this class on classes that do not implement `IXmlSerializable` but have the `[Serializable]` attribute.  How could I go about doing this?

From my generic class:

```
public static class XmlSerializationUtils<T> where T : IXmlSerializable
{
    public static T DeserializeXml(XmlDocument xml) { ... }
    public static XmlDocument SerializeToXml(T toSerialize) { ... }
}
```

I found [this discussion](http://www.techtalkz.com/c-c-sharp/172451-generics-how-have-constraint-attribute.html) but there was no solution given, just that I can't do `where T : Serializable`.  Trying to do `where T : SerializableAttribute` makes Visual Studio say "Cannot use sealed class 'System.SerializableAttribute' as type parameter constraint".

**Edit:** based on [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291990/c-generic-serialization-utility-class/3292006#3292006), I removed the constraints on `XmlSerializationUtils<T>` and added this static constructor:

```
static XmlSerializationUtils()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    bool hasAttribute = null != Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type,
        typeof(SerializableAttribute));
    bool implementsInterface =
        null != type.GetInterface(typeof(IXmlSerializable).FullName);
    if (!hasAttribute && !implementsInterface)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Cannot use XmlSerializationUtils on class " + type.Name +
            " because it does not have the Serializable attribute " +
            " and it does not implement IXmlSerializable"
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't require an attribute as part of generics.  However, you could provide a static constructor that checks for it and throws if it's not found.

Answer (score 8):

You can check to see if a type is serializable using the [IsSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx) property of the Type of the object.

```
myObj.GetType().IsSerializable
```

As mentioned, this isn't possible to add as a generic constraint, but would most likely be checked in a constructor.

Comment: This is better than checking for the attribute.  Thanks.

Comment: Hm.  My current solution (in my question) checks to see if `IXmlSerializable` or `[Serializable]` applies to the given class `T`.  Does `IsSerializable` account for both?

Comment: Apparently.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I'd just eliminate the type constraint and catch the SerializationException when the type does not serialize or deserialize properly... In fact, this allows your generic Serialize and Deserialize methods to accept a formatter

```
public enum Formatter { Binary, Xml }
```

that could control whether the serialization is binary or Xml

```
public class Serialization
{
    public enum Formatter { Binary, Xml }

    #region Serialization methods
    public static void Serialize2File<T>(T obj, string pathSpec, 
        Formatter formatter)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (formatter)
            {
                case (Formatter.Binary):
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(pathSpec, FileMode.Create,
                                        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                        (new BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(fs, obj);
                    break;

                case (Formatter.Xml):
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(pathSpec);
                    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
                    textWriter.Close();
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new MyCustomException("Invalid Formatter option");
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException sX)
        {
            var errMsg = String.Format(
                "Unable to serialize {0} into file {1}",
                obj, pathSpec);
            throw new MyCustomException(errMsg, sX);
        }
    }
    public static T DeSerializeFromFile<T>(string pathSpec, 
        Formatter formatter) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            switch (formatter)
            {
                case (Formatter.Binary):
                    using (var strm = new FileStream(pathSpec,
                                        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        IFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
                        var o = fmt.Deserialize(strm);
                        if (!(o is T))
                            throw new ArgumentException("Bad Data File");
                        return o as T;
                    }

                case (Formatter.Xml):
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(pathSpec);
                    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);

                default:
                    throw new MyCustomException("Invalid Formatter option");
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException sX)
        {
            var errMsg = String.Format(
                "Unable to deserialize {0} from file {1}",
                typeof(T), pathSpec);
            throw new MyCustomException(errMsg, sX);
        }
    }
    #endregion Serialization methods
}
```

Comment: That's not an unreasonable solution.

Comment: Yeah i agree, it is being used by a developer who whould know whether the class he is trying to serialise is serliasable, if he uses it wrong that is what exceptions are for, you cannot eliminate every posible bug at compile time.

Comment: @Ben: We can't always do so, but we should certainly try to catch bugs early and often.  In this case, we can't catch it at compile time, but if we use the static constructor trick, we can catch it at the very start of run time (which means a post-compile smoke check will not miss it).

Comment: When I origianlly coded this, I had code in the class to detect, (only when attempting Xml Serialization), if the passed in Type variable implemented `IXmlSerializable`, or (using Reflection), was decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute... Then WCF came out and they added the `[DataContract]` attribute, which also allows a type to be serialized as Xml. So I removed it...

Answer (score 0):

## C# generic serialization utility class.

The core of serializing classes that implement the **IXmlSerializable** or **Serializable** attribute is to check the given type before passing it to the serializer.

```cs
XmlDocument Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (type.HasAttribute<SerializableAttribute>()
      | type.ImplementsInterface<IXmlSerializableAttribute>())
        return XmlSerializer<T>.Serialize(obj);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unserializable object given.");
}
```

To do this, you should implement the following extension methods and a generic serializer.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace System
{
    public static partial class Extensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the object <see cref="Type"/> has the specified attribute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">
        /// Object <see cref="Type"/> for which you want to check whether
        /// whether it has <see cref="Attribute"/> specified by the <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </param>
        public static bool HasAtribute<T>(this Type type) where T : Attribute
        {
            return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).Any();
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the object <see cref="Type"/> implements the specified interface.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">
        /// Object <see cref="Type"/> for which you want to check whether
        /// whether it implements the interface specified by the <paramref name="interfaceType"/> parameter.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="interfaceType">
        /// The <see cref="Type"/> being tested, which is an interface.
        /// </param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="type"/> is not a class, value type, or interface,
        /// and also if <paramref name="interfaceType"/> is not an interface.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
        /// The value <see langword="null"/> was passed as one of the parameters.
        /// </exception>
        /// <returns>
        /// <see langword="true"/> if the object <see cref="Type"/> implements the specified interface.
        /// </returns> 
        public static bool ImplementsInterface(this Type type, Type interfaceType)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
            if (interfaceType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(interfaceType));
            if (!interfaceType.IsInterface)
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be interface.", 
                    nameof(interfaceType));

            while (type != null)
            {
                Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
                {
                    int length = interfaces.Length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    {
                        if (interfaces[i] == interfaceType || interfaces[i].ImplementsInterface(interfaceType))
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the object <see cref="Type"/> implements the specified interface.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type being checked, which is an interface.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="type">
        /// Object <see cref="Type"/> for which you want to check whether
        /// whether it implements the specified interface <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <see langword="true"/> if the object is <see cref="Type"/>
        /// implements the <typeparamref name="T"/> interface.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="type"/> is not a class, value type, or interface.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
        /// The value <see langword="null"/> was passed as <paramref name="type"/>.
        /// </exception>
        public static bool ImplementsInterface<T>(this Type type) where T : class =>
            ImplementsInterface(type, typeof(T)); 

    }
}

namespace System.Xml.Serialization
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes and deserializes <typeparamref name="T"/> objects into XML documents.
    /// Allows you to control the process of encoding objects in XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Object type.</typeparam>
    public static class XmlSerializer<T>
    {
        private static readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        private static readonly XmlWriterSettings _defaultWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            CheckCharacters = false,
            CloseOutput = false,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
            Encoding = DefaultEncoding,
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t",
            NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates,
            NewLineChars = "\r\n",
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
            NewLineOnAttributes = false,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = false
        };
        private static readonly XmlReaderSettings _defaultReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            CheckCharacters = false,
            CloseInput = false,
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit,
            IgnoreComments = true,
            IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
            IgnoreWhitespace = true,
            LineNumberOffset = 0,
            LinePositionOffset = 0,
            MaxCharactersFromEntities = 0,
            MaxCharactersInDocument = 0,
            NameTable = null,
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None,
            ValidationType = ValidationType.None,
            XmlResolver = null
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Default character encoding.
        /// </summary>
        public static Encoding DefaultEncoding => Encoding.UTF8;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default settings for the <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance being created.
        /// </summary>
        public static XmlWriterSettings DefaultXmlWriterSettings => _defaultWriterSettings.Clone();

        /// <summary>
        /// Default settings for the <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance that is created.
        /// </summary>
        public static XmlReaderSettings DefaultXmlReaderSettings => _defaultReaderSettings.Clone();

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes the given object and returns an XML document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">
        /// An instance <typeparamref name="T"/> to serialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlWriter" /> instance.
        /// If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlWriterSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="XmlDocument"/> that represents given object.</returns>
        public static XmlDocument Serialize(T o, XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings ?? DefaultXmlWriterSettings))
                _serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, o, (XmlSerializerNamespaces)null);
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
            return xmlDocument;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the object contained in the specified XML document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlDocument">
        /// An XML document containing the serialized data.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="settings">
        /// Settings for the new <see cref="XmlReader" /> instance.
        /// If <see langword="null"/> is specified,
        /// settings are used <see cref="DefaultXmlReaderSettings"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns> The deserialized object of type <typeparamref name="T"/>. </returns>
        public static T Deserialize(XmlDocument xmlDocument, XmlReaderSettings settings)
        {
            string text = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text))
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, DefaultXmlReaderSettings))
                return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a value indicating whether this <see cref="XmlSerializer" /> can deserialize the specified XML document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlReader">
        /// <see cref="XmlReader" /> Pointing to the document to deserialize.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <see langword="true" /> If this <see cref="XmlSerializer" /> can deserialize an object, <see cref="XmlReader" /> indicates; otherwise, <see langword="false" />.
        /// </returns>
        public static bool CanDeserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            return _serializer.CanDeserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```